# Animate three card depends on scrolling value

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

I have three card in horizontal, i just want animate them like this https://www.bluelabellabs.com/work/delve/ (the Result Section)

[image]

My JS Code:

```
  `window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const cardOne = document.getElementById("box_one")
    const cardTwo = document.getElementById("box_two")
    const cardThree = document.getElementById("box_three")
    const scrollYValue = window.scrollY;

    $(window).scroll(function () { 
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 2) {
        const cardOne = document.getElementById("box_one")
        const cardTwo = document.getElementById("box_two")
        const cardThree = document.getElementById("box_three")
        const scrollYValue = window.scrollY;
        
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          var position = $(window).scrollTop();
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            // console.log(scroll, position);
            if (scroll >= position) {
              console.log("Up");
                cardOne.style.transform = "translate3d(0px, " + -scrollYValue / 200 + "em, 0px)",
                cardTwo.style.transform = "translate3d(0px, " + -scrollYValue / 600 + "em, 0px)",
                cardThree.style.transform = `translateY(${scrollYValue / 30}px)`
              } else if (scroll <= position) { 
                console.log("back");
                cardOne.style.transform = "translate3d(0px, " + scrollYValue  + "px, 0px)",
                cardTwo.style.transform = `translateY(${-scrollYValue / 90}px)`
                cardThree.style.transform = `translateY(${-scrollYValue / 30}px)`
            }
            position = scroll;
        });
      } 
    });
  })`
```